# Concatenating and timing 2 date/time fields together

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to teach myself some SQL and can't figure out the best way to do the below

```
SELECT [BasicStartDateTime]
  ,[BasicFinishTime]
,cast (BasicStartDateTime as varchar(120)) + '-' + CAST(BasicFinishTime as varchar(7))as TimeBand 
FROM [DOCDPT].[main].[Tbl_WorkOrder]
where BasicStartDateTime >'2017-01-01'
```

These are my resulting columns

BasicStartDateTime

```
2017-01-03 12:00:00.000
```

BasicFinishTime

```
20:00:00.000
```

TimeBand

```
Jan  3 2017 12:00PM-8:00PM
```

Ideally I'd want the final column (Time band) to say `12:00-20:00`.

What I was trying to get to first is `12:00pm-8:00Pm` and then I am going to worry about 24 hour clock bit afterwards

I've been trying to use convert and right in the first phase on the concatenation but the syntax never seems to work.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

If 2012+

One should note that Format() has some great functionality, but it is not known as a performer.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([BasicStartDateTime] datetime,[BasicFinishTime] datetime)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('2017-01-03 12:00:00.000','2017-01-03 20:00:00.000')

Select * 
      ,TimeBand = format(BasicStartDateTime,'HH:mm-')+format(BasicFinishTime,'HH:mm')
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
BasicStartDateTime        BasicFinishTime           TimeBand
2017-01-03 12:00:00.000   2017-01-03 20:00:00.000   12:00-20:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), BasicStartDateTime, 100), 7)) + '-' +
LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), cast(BasicFinishTime AS datetime), 100), 7))
```

Answer (score 0):

using [**`convert()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) styles, and transforming your `basicfinishtime` to a `datetime` prior to converting to `varchar`:

```
select 
    basicstartdatetime
  , basicfinishtime
  , timeband = convert(varchar(20), basicstartdatetime, 100)
    +'-'+ltrim(right(convert(varchar(20), convert(datetime,basicfinishtime),100),7))
from tbl_workorder
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/YDMCD58620

returns:

```
+---------------------+-----------------+----------------------------+
| basicstartdatetime  | basicfinishtime |          timeband          |
+---------------------+-----------------+----------------------------+
| 2017-01-03 12:00:00 | 20:00:00        | Jan  3 2017 12:00PM-8:00PM |
+---------------------+-----------------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: I'm trying to remove the date part from the time band but I'll have a look at trying to convert what you've put in a bit.  I'd looked at using Ltrim/Rtrim but I thought I read that that only removed blank characters.